# <DropDownBox /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements

Tags: reactjs

```
const Components2 = () => {
return (
    <div className="container">
        {Data.map(Data => <form key={Data.id}>
            <label>{Data.name}:</label>
            <Data.Type/>
        </form>)}
    </div>
)}

[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Effective Date",
"Type":"DropDownBox"
}]
```

I need to create a custom control component tag in react from json by taking value from json file and place in btw in <Data.type/> tag and create a custom component as <DropDownBox./>.

Comment: this article will help you. https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json

Comment: it not working in my case

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.